# Copying a specific column from one existing excel file to another file in python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, openpyxl

I am successfully copying the whole columns from one existing excel file to another file in python, but cannot copy a specific column from an existing excel file and writing it into another.

> Here is my code

```
wb = load_workbook('Ambulance2Centroids_16622.xlsx')
wb2 = load_workbook('test.xlsx')

sheet1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
sheet2 = wb2.get_sheet_by_name('Details')

for i in range (1, 10):
    for j in range (1, sheet1.max_column+1):
        sheet2.cell(row=i, column=j).value = sheet1.cell(row=i, column=j).value
wb.save('Ambulance2Centroids_16622.xlsx')
wb2.save('test.xlsx')
```

[image]

> Here, i am trying to get FROM_ID only.

Comment: If you only want `FROM_ID`, just set `j = 1` instead of looping it over a range of values with a `for` loop. Or maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to note:
The **get_sheet_by_name** attribute is depreciated you should just use **wb[<sheetname>]** as shown below.
There is no need to save a workbook (wb) that you have not changed. Since you are only reading data from **'Ambulance2Centroids_16622.xlsx'** to copy to **'test.xlsx'** there are no changes to that wb and no need to save it.
The example below shows how to find the column in the original wb, in this case 'FROM_ID' and then copy the column to the destination wb 'test.xlsx'.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('Ambulance2Centroids_16622.xlsx')
wb2 = load_workbook('test.xlsx')

# Use wb[<sheetname>] to assign sheets to variable 
sheet1 = wb['Sheet1']
sheet2 = wb2['Details']

search_text = 'FROM_ID'

for header_row in sheet1[1]:  # sheet1[1] means iterate row 1, header row
    if header_row.value == search_text:
        # Use the column letter of the found column to iterate the originating column and copy the cell value
        for dest_row, orig_col_c in enumerate(sheet1[header_row.column_letter], 1):  
            # Copying the originating cell value to column A (1) in destination wb  
            sheet2.cell(row=dest_row, column=1).value = orig_col_c.value

# Save test.xlsx only
# wb.save('Ambulance2Centroids_16622.xlsx')
wb2.save('test.xlsx')
```

Comment: Use `iter_rows()` wherever you can.